# How to make socket-io work even after app close

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I have been building a chat application in react native. For the bi-directional communication i have used socket-io. Socket-io works only when the app is in foreground, it doesn't work when the app is in background or closed channel disconnects. So how do i keep channel connected even when the app is in background or closed. Is there any background services in react native.

Comment: I'm inclined to say you might need a web worker. I think they're always on, while the page is open somewhere. That means you'll have to reformat to a pwa.

Comment: Yes, there are . Please do research thoroughly. Try looking up "React Native background service"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HeadlessJSTask](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) for android to ensure a service is always working while you app is in background. However there is no such thing in iOS and also iOS is very strict with background jobs so you need to accept iOS as it is. Please update here if you find any such thing for iOS. Would be glad to learn.